# Is Visual Format Language really useful in iOS when we can make constraints and Anchors at runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, visual-format-language

Even Xcode provides very easy to use story board via which making UI of an app is quite easy.

But some time we come in situations when we have to use CODE to manage the design aspects of our app.

I generally use Anchors and Constraints to handle this stuff via code but there is also another way of doing it i.e.., "Visual Format Language". Is there really any difference between using any of the methods or they are same what are the advantages or disadvantages of using one or other.

Answer (score 6):

The old-style NSLayoutConstraint initializer was a pain in the butt, so the visual format syntax was a welcome alternative. Now that we have *another* alternative, namely the Anchors notation, making a single constraint by hand is not very cumbersome, and the visual format notation is not as useful as it used to be. Moreover there are many important constraint notions that visual format syntax is incapable of expressing; this was always a shortcoming.

Visual format syntax can be extremely handy when you have a *row* (or column) of objects to configure all at once, e.g. `"|-(20)-[v1]-(30)-[v2]-(20)-[v3]"`. This is because of the ability of one format string to generate many constraints at once.

However, now that we have UIStackViews with the ability to specify spacing after individual views, even that use of visual format syntax pretty much falls away.

Comment: Another nice thing about the visual format language is the ability to add layout options. These let you align all views along the other axis in one easy step.

Comment: @nils Good addition.

Comment: I rarely use the Visual Format Language these days anymore. UIStackViews are super powerful and easy to use.

Comment: @nils I think I should add that to the answer. Thanks!